# Saving Multiple New Entities in a Single Hibernate Transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, ejb-3.0, cascade

I'm trying to create an EJB service method that creates two new entity objects and associates them with each other and with an existing entity. The relationships between the classes looks like this:

```
ClassA 1:N ClassB
ClassA 1:N ClassC
ClassB 1:N ClassC
```

Currently, all the relationships are Bidirectional and I have the CascadeType for each relationship set to 'ALL'. The instance of ClassA will be looked up using the entity manager. ClassB and ClassC are new instances that get created as part of this method. What I want to do is set up the relationships, persist all the changes, and return the updated instance of ClassC. The problem is, when I actually try to commit the transaction, I always get errors like this:

> "(javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active:
>   tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff7f000001:126a:50b6222c:c2
>   status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >)"

Does anyone have an idea of how to go about doing something like this?

Comment: Can you share your save method code? Looks like transaction is not being created or method is not marked as @transactional.

Comment: At the end of the method I'm doing something like this:              instanceC = entityManager.persist(instanceC); return instanceC;

Answer (score 0):

You probably catched an error coming from a transactionnal method (annodated with `@TransactionAttribute`) which already marked the transaction as rolled back, so the current transaction is no longer valid (already rolled back by the container) at the time you commit.